# Nodelist getAttribute IE11 JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, nodelist, getattribute

I am currently having an issue with the getAttribute() method.

This currently works in IE8, but in IE11 I recieve the error **Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'**.

The same issue happens when I use hasAttribute() at the same point.

The error is thrown when you reach **if(discounts[j].getAttribute("id") == discountId)**, and if I try to console.log the id, I get **Undefined**.

I did manage to get it to work in IE11 by running in compatibility mode, but that is not an option.

This is the method I am currently using below.

```
        if(discountsXml != null && discountsXml.documentElement != null) {


            var invItems = discountsXml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("invItem");
            var invItemsCounter = invItems.length;
            var i = 0;

            for(i=0; i<invItemsCounter; i++) {

                if(invItems[i].getAttribute("id") == invItemId) {

                    var discounts = invItems[i].childNodes;
                    var discountsCounter = discounts.length;
                    var j = 0;
                    for(j=0; j<discountsCounter; j++) {
                        if(discounts[j].getAttribute("id") == discountId) {
                            discount = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. Does it work in other browsers? Have you tried examining the object using `console.log(invItems[i])` to see what it actually contains? What does discountsXml contain? (I can guess from the name, but be explicit). And finally, can you provide a functioning demo of the problem either here or somewhere like jsfiddle? Cut it down to the minimum code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't include enough detail about your web page to offer much in the way of useful advice, but it sounds like you're relying on legacy behavior at some point outside of the code sample you've posted.  IE11 removes support for [many legacy behaviors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#legacyAPIs) in favor of more modern approaches.  The fact that the code works in IE8 and a legacy document mode is telling.  For example, how are you populating the XML data?  Compare the data types between IE11 and IE8; you should find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually ask a question above so I'm not sure on the best answer,
But would it be possible for you to use the id property instead of the id attribute as is generally recommended?

```
invItems[i].id vs invItems[i].getAttribute("id")
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp